# Node webkit and Google OAuth

Tags: node.js, oauth, popup, node-webkit, google-authentication

Just starting out with node webkit and I'm simply loading a website through an iframe to start...(I know, dirty but gets the job done with 2 hands and a bit of time).

```
<iframe src="http://somewebsite.com"></iframe>
```

The thing is, I have Google login for the site, which creates a pop up on the website. For some reason, it doesn't in node-webkit and I can't find any doc about enabling popups...

The code I'm using for the Google login is the default one they give us on the site: 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login

I'm currently not setting anything exciting in the node-webkit configuration:

```
"window": {
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 768,
    "min_width": 300,
    "min_height": 300,
    "position": "center",
    "resizable": true,
    "show_in_taskbar": true,
    "icon": "www/resources/img/icon.png"
},
```

So my question is, how can I enable popups on node-webkit from an iframe to get the Google OAuth working? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this is the limitation of node webkit, and it is known issue in their github, and they are trying to fix thing, you could check their github page

Comment: I have the same issue, you can solve this? On versions > 0.10.5.rc1  with this fragment:

nw.App.addOriginAccessWhitelistEntry('http://IPSERVER0/', 'app', 'myapp', true);

But on older versions like 0.8.6 doesnt work that. I post my issue here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933087/how-to-apply-addoriginaccesswhitelistentry-on-node-webkit-0-8-6[/link]

Comment: I wish. I even put a bounty on this a while back with no response. If you do find a solution, please let us know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by authorizing the node context to remote sites.

Simply add the [node-remote](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format#node-remote) configuration item to your *package.json* file. (But be warned that this can cause some libraries to load differently as they will detect the change in context).

```
{
    node-remote : "*" // Or the src url of your iframe
}
```

Google login should be working fine after that.

Answer (score 1):

Sicne this has been posted "node-remote" has change slightly.  Here is an example:

```
"node-remote": "*://*",
```

**Direct Links:**

- Notes about changes from v0.12 to v0.13 - http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/
- Formatting of node-remote